# turn a pivot table from pandas into a flat tabular format with a single header row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What's the easiest way to turn my pandas dataframe into a dataframe which has one header row and the two columns

from this:

```
          date  today
index       
1   2016-07-01  2016-09-08
2   2016-07-01  2016-09-08
3   2016-07-01  2016-09-08
4   2016-07-01  2016-09-08
```

into this:

```
index      date     today   
1   2016-07-01  2016-09-08
2   2016-07-01  2016-09-08
3   2016-07-01  2016-09-08
4   2016-07-01  2016-09-08
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.columns)
Index(['date', 'today'], dtype='object')

print (df.index)
Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64', name='index')

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Or:

```
df = df.reset_index()

print (df)
   index        date       today
0      1  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
1      2  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
2      3  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
3      4  2016-07-01  2016-09-08

print (df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)
```

---

If need remove column `index`, add parameter `drop=True`:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print (df)
         date       today
0  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
1  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
2  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
3  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
```

But if need only remove text `index` use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

Or:

```
#all versions
df.index.name = None

print (df)
         date       today
1  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
2  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
3  2016-07-01  2016-09-08
4  2016-07-01  2016-09-08

print (df.index)
Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Please check my solutions, now I am little confused if I understand what need exactly.